# Running the current program in Eclipse Helios results in showing the previous program's output

Tags: java, eclipse

I checked the solutions here but it didn't worked for me.. I enabled the Build
Automatically.. Checked the Build path,Source tab, changed the output folder from bin to src but Nothing went my way. Can anyone help me regarding this.. I have just started working on eclipse.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't clicking the Green arrow button that runs the previous program? Make sure you select the correct program in the dropdown. You can also clear the console output with the "x"

Comment: It might help when you check `Run / Run configurations`. There you can see which classes are run and invoke them directly.

Comment: m using Ctrl+f11 which is similar to green arrow button. and yes when pointing to that button it shows a default file say S21 n whenever m compiling, the console is showing that default output only. So to compile a new file every time i need to go to run configurations.. n type the name of that file.and again its taking that as a default. So what m i supposed to do now? Do i have to do this explicitly for every file i create?

Comment: Well i figured out what was the problem.. I had developed a file with two classes and was compiling the class with no main(). That's why the compiler was showing the previous results in console. Extremely sorry for my stupidity. Should have focused earlier on this.. :( But Thank you all for showing #gratitude.   @BrandonLing

Comment: @Ayush no worries, it happens even to me (countless times). glad you found out how to fix it